# Find minimization of the difference between integrals of exponential decay, and step exponential decay functions

Tags: integration, optimization, exponential-function

I am trying to equate two integrals, one of exponential decay and another of exponential decay that drops with a step (floor) function. Specifically, I am trying to minimize the difference of these decays given values for $g_1$ and $s$ over $g_2$.  Here is the resulting minimization:

$$
\operatorname*{argmin}_{g_2} \Bigg|\Bigg| \small \int_0^T g_1^{\lfloor t/s \rfloor} \, dt - \int_0^T g_2^t \, dt \Bigg|\Bigg| \\[10pt]
\{g_1, g_2\in\mathbb{R} , 0 < g_1, g_2 < 1\} \\[10pt]
\{T, S \in \mathbb{N}, 0 < s < T \}
$$

We can assume that $T$ will be an integer multiple of $s$:

$$
\operatorname*{argmin}_{g_2} \Bigg|\Bigg| \small \int_0^{Ns} g_1^{\lfloor t/s \rfloor} \, dt - \int_0^{Ns} g_2^t \, dt \Bigg|\Bigg| \\[10pt]
\{N \in \mathbb{N}, N>0\}
$$

So far I am having no luck in find a solution to this.

I've tried converting the left-hand integral to a summation, and solving the right-hand integral, but I still get stuck at:

$$
s\sum_0^{Ns-1}{g_1^n} - \frac{g_2^{Ns} - 1}{\log g_2}
$$

An approximate solution is also ok, but I didn't find the series expansion to help.

P.S. My math formatting may be wrong all over the place.  If so, please help me correct it.

Comment: There are some flaws in your series expansion: $$ \int_0^{Ns} g_1^{\lfloor t/s \rfloor} \, dt = \int_0^N g_1^{\lfloor u \rfloor} (s \, du) = s \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} g_1^n = s \cdot \frac{g_1^N - 1}{g_1 - 1} = \frac{g_2^{Ns} - 1}{\log g_2}$$

Comment: So you have $$ \frac{g_2^{Ns} - 1}{\log g_2} = \text{constant} $$ where "constant" means not depending on $g_2. \qquad$

Comment: Sure, but I want $g_2$ in terms of $g_1$ and $s$ to minimize the difference between the two integrals.

Answer (score 0):

$$
\int_0^{Ns}g_1^{\lfloor t/s \rfloor} \, dt = \int_0^N g_1^{\lfloor u \rfloor} (s\,dt) = s \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} g_1^n = s \cdot \frac{g_1^N - 1}{g_1 - 1} = \frac{g_2^{Ns} - 1}{\log g_2}
$$
So you have
$$
\frac{g_2^{Ns} - 1}{\log g_2} = \text{constant}
$$
where "constant" means not depending on $g_2$.

From $\displaystyle \frac{g_2^{Ns} - 1}{\log g_2} = c$ we get $\displaystyle g_2^{Ns} = 1+c\log g_2 = \log(g_2^c\cdot e).$

As $g_2\downarrow 1$, the fraction $\dfrac{g_2^{Ns} - 1}{\log g_2}$ approaches $Ns$. The fraction grows without bound as $g_2$ grows, so if $Ns<c$, then there must be some value of $g_2>1$ for which equality holds.

For this I think I would use Newton's method.

Comment: Also 0 < g1, g2 < 1. I'll update

Comment: I updated the question a bit, to make it more clear what I am trying to obtain.  Basically given a value for $g_1$ and $s$ I want to find a value of $g_2$ that minimizes the difference between the two integrals.